# Is it possible to open an incognito window in Selenium IDE chrome extension?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-ide, incognito-mode

I am automating a flow of two users. So one user is being logged in the Chrome and another should be logging in through the Incognito mode. The cookies and cache should stay the same, they cannot be cleaned at the moment.
Is there any possibility to open an **Incognito window** using **Selenium IDE Chrome extension**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium ***IDE*** ***does not*** ***officially*** support ***incognito mode***

You can look into [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/914) and [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/442)